# Server won't boot after adding two new disks

Tags: hp-smart-array, raid5

I have an HP ML350 G6 server with 3 600Gb SAS drives on RAID5. I added 2 new 1Tb disks and configured a new Array with RAID1. Al of a sudden I got the blue screen of death, the server rebooted and now I get operating system not found. I've run the RAID diagnostics booting from Smart CD  and there are no Critical Errors or Alerts, just an Information Statis MEssage on Array A with code 785 saying "Backround parity initialization is currently queued or in progress on Logica Drive1 (1.1Tb RAID5) if backround parity initialization is queued it wil start when I/O is performed on the dirve.When backround parity initialization completes the performance of the logical drive will improve"

Comment: Does it boot if you remove the disks?

Comment: No, it doesn't either.

Comment: Update: I'm no longer getting the Statis Message on Array A with code 785. The RAID and disks are coming up with no errors on the diagnostics but I still can't boot from them. It says no operating system found. Any advice on how to see if the data is still on there and how to retrieve it? I have a backup but it's from the previous night, so there's a days work missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.